Github Copilot but for other things than code
I’m looking for an AI writing tool that would basically work the same as Github Copilot but would not be limited to coding questions. Specifically, I would like:

the ability for the AI to suggest a paragraph or two when I add a comment in my file such as:
% write a paragraph about why the sky is blue

to be able to highlight some text, and then ask in the "chat":
rewrite #selection so that it can be understood by a 5 years old child


and with the click of the button the generated text would replace the highlighted text.
Does a tool like this exist?

I believe that Microsoft Copilot can do this kind of thing with its Word integration.

The Gemini product line of AI apps and models (by Google) may be able to do this while you are drafting emails or writing documents. The feature is called "Help me write..." at this time. You need to get a Google account, then work in the cloud, inside the Chrome browser.
